# Не редактируются файлы bitrix

Tags: html, битрикс

я с битриксом на "Вы", видоизменяю сейчас мобильное меню, нашел файлы которые его генерят с админки типа:

`<div class="mobilemenu-v1 scroller">
    <div class="wrap">
        <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
            "bitrix:menu",`

для проверки решил просто видо-изменить немного обвертку, добавив к классу "wrap", дополнительный класс, перезагрузил файл, обновил сайт, но ничего не изменилось.
В том, что это этот файл у меня сомнения нет, так как подключаются ниже модули которые используются на сайте.

Может кто подскажет, есть ли какая то особенность работы с файлами в битриксе, может кеш какой то есть, или версию файла как то нужно отдельно обновлять? 
Спасибо

Comment: да нет никаких особенностей. В битриксе все в файлах. Открываете нужный Вам файл , редактором или IDE и правите. Результаты сразу появятся. Кэш есть , но для этого в разделе "Сайт" есть кнопка "Сбросить Кэш"

Comment: @Prakto leb , все-таки мне кажется Вы не тот файл открыли. Как Вы это сделали? зашли на нужную Вам страницу и нажаили "Изменить страницу в режиме php-кода" ?

Comment: Добрый день, не совсем (редактирую меню) запустил поиск по директориях (определенного участка кода) тега и класса (html) нашло лишь несколько файлов (версии от темы которые не используются) и один полноценный файл в котором, прописаны подключения всех модулей которые используются в меню. (редактирование файлов произвожу через редактор кода не на сайте, а на компьютере

Comment: @Prakto leb да не надо так делать, заходите на сайт на нужную Вам страницу. Вверху в панели Битрикса жмёте  "Изменить страницу в режиме php-кода" и вверху в заголовке написан полный путь до файла который Вам нужен, можно прям здесь править и сохранять, можно открыть редактором.

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, вы не тот файл правите. Файлы могут быть идентичны, но лежать в разных местах.

В файле, где вызывается ваше меню есть код типа такого:

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:menu", "vertical_multilevel", Array(
"ROOT_MENU_TYPE" => "catalog",      // Тип меню для первого уровня
"MENU_CACHE_TYPE" => "Y",           // Тип кеширования
"MENU_CACHE_TIME" => "36000000",    // Время кеширования (сек.)
```

со своими параметрами на месте

```
("bitrix:menu", "vertical_multilevel",
```

Такая запись говорит, что файл template.php, в котором и есть html-код вашего меню расположен в одном месте из:

```
1) /bitrix/components/bitrix/menu/templates/vertical_multilevel
2) /bitrix/templates/.default/bitrix/components/menu/vertical_multilevel
3) /local/components....
```

Вот ссылка на документацию https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2826&LESSON_PATH=3913.4565.2826